# Excel Power Query Custom Function Editor to Catch Not Found Value

Tags: excel, powerquery, custom-functions-excel

Need guidance adding a catch error for NPI value not found from API. This table has 2000 NPI numbers and some of them will not be found in the API call. When I run this function it stops and errors out when it finds no match. I want the function to continue and put the error on the appropriate line.

```
let
Source = (NPPES_API as any) => let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?version=2.1&number=" & NPPES_API)),
    results = Source[results],
    results1 = results{0},
    addresses = results1[addresses],
    addresses1 = addresses{0},
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(addresses1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Converted to Table",{"Name"}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Removed Columns",4),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Top Rows", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))
in
    #"Removed Blank Rows"
in
Source
```

Comment: cant you wrap the function in   try .....   otherwise null   ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how that syntax would look? I used built-in helper in Excel to write the above.

Answer (score 1):

The server seems to include an `Errors` field in its responses when you search for a non-existent or invalid NPI number. So maybe check for this condition and then accordingly expand the response.

Example implementation is below for a list of NPI numbers (one of which is deliberately invalid for the purposes of eliciting and handling an error response from the server).

```
let
    npiNumbers = {"1245319599", "abc"},
    getDataForNpiNumber = (someNpiNumber as text) as record =>
        let
            json = Web.Contents("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/", [
                Query = [version = "2.1", number = someNpiNumber]
            ]),
            parsed = Json.Document(json),
            row = [
                npiNumber = someNpiNumber,
                data = Table.FromRecords(Record.FieldOrDefault(parsed, "results", {})),
                errors = Table.FromRecords(Record.FieldOrDefault(parsed, "Errors", {}))
            ]
        in row,
    rows = List.Transform(npiNumbers, getDataForNpiNumber),
    data = Table.FromRecords(rows)
in
    data
```

It should give you a table containing a row for each NPI number requested. Each row itself should contain 3 fields:

- `npiNumber` (the NPI number requested)
- `data` (data received from the server for this NPI number, or an empty table if an error occurred)
- `errors` (errors received from the server for this NPI number, or an empty table if the request was successfully fulfilled by the server)

You can then expand the table's rows and drill down as necessary (since you've not described what you want to do with the data or how you need it to be structured).